# Linq with conditional joins

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I couldn't convert the following left join SQL to linq:

```
select  Students.StudentID, StudentAddresses.state
from Students left join Studentaddresses on (Students.StudentID = Studentaddresses.StudentID and StudentAddresses.Active=1)
where (StudentAddresses.Rank =1  or StudentAddresses.StudentID is null)
and Students.StudentID =3
```

A student can have zero record or multiple records in the Student Address table, but only one of the records can be active and rank=1.

I was able to do a left join in linq and make it work for normal situation. But if a student has two inactive records in the Student table, I don't know how to make the student record appear only once in the final result. Can anyone please help?

Comment: sorry, I meant " if a student has two inactive records in the StudentAddress table, I don't know how to make the student record appear only once in the final result." A student can only have one active address with rank =1, this is the only rule in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Distinct()` to collapse duplicates.

```
var LeftJoin = (from student in Students
                join address in (from address1 in StudentAddresses where address.Active select address1) 
                on student.StudentID equals address.StudentId
                into JoinedStudentAddress
                from joined in JoinedStudentAddress.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new                          
                {
                    StudentID = student.StudentID,
                    State = joined != null ? joined.State : null
                }).Distinct();
```

Alternate syntax

```
 var LeftJoin = Students.GroupJoin( StudentAddress.Where( a => a.Active ),
                                    s => s.StudentID,
                                    a => a.StudentID,
                                    (s,a) => new { Student = s, Addresses = a } )
                        .SelectMany( j = > j.Addresses.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     (s,a) => new {
                                                 StudentID = s.Student.StudentID,
                                                 State = a != null ? a.State : null
                                    })
                        .Distinct();
```

Comment: I think `on student.StudentID = address.StudentId and address.Active` should be `on student.StudentID equals address.StudentId where address.Active`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I was adapting an example I found elsewhere.  I don't actually use LINQ syntax, preferring the fluent notation.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated.

Comment: Thank you! But the system wouldn't let me put a "where" clause before the "into", because it considers the "where" ends the query.

Comment: @user1040356 - changed it to use a sub query

Comment: I think I probably end up with using a stored procedure to do this. There are too many conditions I need to consider to produce the right result set (one student has to appear once and only once regardless how many address records they have). Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the SQL statement converted to linq:

```
var q = from student in Students
        from adress in Studentaddresses.Where(x => student.StudentID == x.StudentID && x.Active).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (adress.Rank == 1 || adress.StudentID == null) && student.StudentID == 3
        select new                          
        {
           StudentID = student.StudentID,
           State = adress.state
        };
```